Docker container stops running immediately without any logs while trying to run Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on M2 MacOS
Docker container stops running immediately without any logs while trying to run Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on M2 MacOS. I tried running it with this command:
% docker run --platform linux/amd64 
--publish 8081:8081 
--publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 
--interactive 
--tty 
mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
after that, I get these logs:
This is an evaluation version.  There are [24] days left in the evaluation period.
2024-04-04 13:18:22 Starting
and then the container randomly stops.
I have followed the official documentation from microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-linux%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql while trying to run this. Does anyone knows why this is happening? Or at least, is there any way to make cosmos db emulation runs on M2 Chip?
% docker run --platform linux/amd64 
--publish 8081:8081 
--publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 
--interactive 
--tty 
mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
Tried this command and it didn't help.

It seems that the Azure Cosmos DB emulator is not currently supported on M1 and M2 chips. A temporary workaround is to install a Windows virtual machine and run the emulator on that platform. As for the issue with the Docker container stopping immediately without any logs, it could be due to a lack of resources.
Running the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on an M2 MacOS can be a bit tricky due to architecture compatibility issues. Docker containers built for the AMD64 platform may not run smoothly on ARM-based chips like the M2. The --platform linux/amd64 flag is a way to attempt to run AMD64 containers on ARM architecture by using emulation.
This behavior you are observing can be due to compatibility issues with the M2 chip or configuration problems within the emulator itself. the Cosmos DB Emulator Docker image does not yet support ARM64, which is the architecture for the M2 chip.
However just try running the container in detached mode as it allows to run in the background and might provide more stability for the container to stay up.Try
docker run --platform linux/amd64 \
  --publish 8081:8081 \
  --publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 \
  --detach \
  mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest

after the container stops, then use docker logs and see what it says
docker logs <container_id_or_name>

Make sure Docker has enough resources (CPU, memory) allocated.
References:

Develop locally using the Azure Cosmos DB emulator (api-nosql)
Run the emulator on Docker for Linux (Preview)
Similar issue

